# Enqueue Stylesheets After Theme's "rtl.css"

Tags: theme-development, localization, css

I am currently developing a theme with internationalization support, and would like to load stylesheets *after* my theme's `rtl.css` (an alternative `style.css` loaded for languages with a right-to-left reading order).

I am familiar with enqueueing my stylesheets and controlling their load order with dependencies using the `wp_register_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions, however `rtl.css` is loaded automatically by WordPress whenever the locale's language direction is `rtl`, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify the stylesheet as a dependency.

I know I can conditionally enqueue stylesheets using the `is_rtl()` function, however 
these stylesheets' `<link>` elements are still printed out before WordPress automatically prints `rtl.css`'s. I could also simply manually insert `<link>`s to the stylesheets that I wish to depend on `rtl.css` right after the call to `wp_head()` in my theme's `header.php` file, but I believe it's bad practice to do so, and I would like my theme to be commercial quality.

How can I load stylesheets after WordPress loads `rtl.css`?

Comment: Which `rtl.css` do you mean precisely? There isn't such exact file in WP core itself (there is in some of native themes though).

Comment: rtl.css file is used when you are designing a theme to work with rtl languages ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Stylesheet Printing Order

WordPress does not load [themes' alternative `rtl.css` files](https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support) using `wp_register_style()` or `wp_enqueue_style()`. As such, the stylesheet does not get added to WordPress's style queue, and cannot be specified as a dependency when registering or enqueueing additional stylesheets.

Instead, this stylesheet's `<link>` element is added via [the `locale_stylesheet()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locale_stylesheet), which is attached to the `wp_head` action. [`wp_print_styles` is hooked to the `wp_head` action with a priority of `8` while `locale_stylesheet()` has the default priority of `10`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L197), which means that all of the styles you enqueue using `wp_enqueue_style()` will **always** be printed out ***before*** `rtl.css`.

> **Note**
>
> `locale_stylesheet()` calls [the `get_locale_stylesheet()`
>   function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale_stylesheet_uri)
>   in order to determine which locale-relevant theme stylesheet to load. First it looks for `{locale}.css` (i.e. `en_US.css`) - if the file doesn't exist it next looks for `{text-direction}.css` (i.e. `rtl.css` or `ltr.css`). Keep in mind that if you supply a `{locale}.css` stylesheet for the current locale, WordPress **will not** automatically load your `rtl.css`

### Solutions

There are a few ways that you can modify this behavior, but it should be noted that it exists for a reason - by loading `rtl.css` after all enqueue'd stylesheets, WordPress provides the theme the opportunity to overwrite any CSS rules provided by plugins and the like that otherwise only support left-to-right languages. All of the solutions I provide below mostly remove this possibility and may create conflicts if any plugins depend on WordPress's default behavior (I can't imagine that many do).

#### Manually Enqueue Your Stylesheet

If you prevent WordPress from automatically loading your `rtl.css` file, you can treat it as you would any other stylesheet, giving you control over when the script loads. There are two ways to accomplish this that come to mind:

- Hook into [an action that fires before `wp_head`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and remove `locale_stylesheet()`'s hook:

  ```
  function remove_locale_stylesheet() {
      remove_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet' );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'remove_locale_stylesheet' );
  ```
- Rename your `rtl.css` file to something else (not `ltr.css` or `{locale}.css`).

After doing one of the above, enqueue your RTL stylesheet as you normally would - conditionally on `is_rtl()` if you also wish to support LTR languages.

#### Reverse `wp_head`'s Stylesheet Printing Order

By hooking into an action before `wp_head` and giving `locale_stylesheet()`'s hook a lower priority than `wp_print_styles`, you can force `rtl.css` to always load before `wp_enqueue_style()`'d stylesheets, effectively making it as though every enqueue'd stylesheet has a dependency on `rtl.css`:

```
function load_locale_style_first() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet' );
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet', 7 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'load_locale_style_first' );
```

Comment: Should rather be a blog post :) +1 ... and maybe a patch for core.

Comment: Another option would be to register stylesheet normally, but print it explicitly (using [wp_print_scripts()](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_print_scripts/) by handle), hooking after rtl thing. On other hand that might create issue with hook inside firing multiple times, because other code might not account for multiple use of the function...

Comment: @kaiser - thanks! I may well write a brief exposé post. I'm not sure if I'm familiar enough with WP i18n/l10n functionality to determine whether a core patch would be beneficial here, though.

Comment: @Rarst - good thoughts all around. I'll play with an implementation tonight and add it to the listed solutions.